# How to stop a function that going through an infinite list

Tags: haskell

I'm basically trying to solve the Project Euler's question number 5. I'm trying to find the smallest number that's divisible by 1-10. I have this so far, and I get the correct answer, but it keeps going on, if I don't stop. How do I make it stop once it finds the first number?

```
set2 :: (Int) -> [Int]
set2 x = [y | y <- [1..10], x `mod` y == 0]

divFunc = [x | x <- [1..], length(set2 x) == 10]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `head` to get the first element of a list.

```
> head divFunc
2520
```

A few other minor comments:

1. Generally people advise against using `head` because it fails on empty lists. It's okay in this particular case because the function you are calling it either has an element (in which case `head` is fine) or thinks infinitely long before producing any useful information (in which case `head` doesn't make the situation any worse). But beware this function in general; you should always have an argument that it is safe (like the above argument) ready to go before you use it.
2. `divFunc` is a funny name. It isn't a function.
3. You may like to look at the `lcm` function.

Comment: I understand about the silly function names and just wanted to whip this up real quick. I could also do this?
`set2 :: (Int) -> [Int]`
`set2 x = [y | y <- [1..10], x \`mod\` y == 0]`

`divFunc = [x | x <- [1..], length(set2 x) == 10]`

`realFunc = head divFunc`

This way, they only need to call realFunc and not have to do head divFunc? I understand what lcm does but when I was looking at question 5 on Project Euler someone answered it like this:
`foldr1 lcm[1..20]`
What does foldr1 do?

Comment: I apologize for the format. I didn't know how to set new lines.

Comment: @humbleCoder I encourage you to try to write this with `lcm` and explicit recursion; then it will be a lot easier to take a look at the implementation of `foldr1` and understand what it does.